# Haskell Tree to List - preorder traversal

Tags: haskell, tree, tree-traversal

Given the following tree structure in Haskell:

```
data Tree = Leaf Int | Node Int Tree Tree deriving Show
```

How can I get Haskell to return a list of the data in pre-order?

e.g. given a tree:

```
Node 1 (Leaf 2) (Leaf 3)
```

return something like:

```
preorder = [1,2,3]
```

Comment: Don't forget to accept an answer once you're satisfied.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, sorry about the late reply, but I got this working as follows:

```
preorder(Leaf n) = [n]
preorder(Node n treeL treeR) = [n] ++ preorder treeL ++ preorder treeR'code'
```

This however does not work for me still

```
preorder (Leaf n) = [n]   
preorder (Node n a b) = n:(preorder a) ++ (preorder b)
```

Answer (score 5):

You could aim to a more general solution and make your data type an instance of `Foldable`.
There is a very similar example at [hackage](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/base/latest/doc/html/Data-Foldable.html), but that implements a post-order visit.
If you want to support pre-order visits you will have to write something like this:

```
import qualified Data.Foldable as F

data Tree a = Leaf a | Node a (Tree a) (Tree a) deriving Show

instance F.Foldable Tree where
    foldr f z (Leaf x) = f x z
    foldr f z (Node k l r) = f k (F.foldr f (F.foldr f z r) l)
```

With this, you'll be able to use every function that works on `Foldable` types, like `elem`, `foldr`, `foldr`, `sum`, `minimum`, `maximum` and such (see [here](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/base/latest/doc/html/Data-Foldable.html#g:6) for reference).

In particular, the list you are searching for can be obtain with `toList`. Here are some examples of what you could write by having that instance declaration:

```
*Main> let t = Node 1 (Node 2 (Leaf 3) (Leaf 4)) (Leaf 5)
*Main> F.toList t
[1,2,3,4,5]
*Main> F.foldl (\a x -> a ++ [x]) [] t
[1,2,3,4,5]
*Main> F.foldr (\x a -> a ++ [x]) [] t
[5,4,3,2,1]
*Main> F.sum t
15
*Main> F.elem 3 t
True
*Main> F.elem 12 t
False
```

Answer (score 3):

Use pattern matching

```
preorder (Leaf n) = [n]
preorder (Node n a b) = n:(preorder a) ++ (preorder b)
```

Comment: I get the following error:
    Couldn't match expected type `[t0]' with actual type `Tree'
    In the pattern: Node n a b
    In an equation for `preorder'
        preorder (Node n a b) = n : (preorder a) ++ (preorder b)

Comment: @Gravy That is bizarre.  Try adding an explicit type signature `preorder :: Tree -> [Int]`.  It doesn't make sense to me that you would be having an error.

Comment: That's weird I just tested it and seems to be working. Are you sure you copied everything correctly?

Comment: @Gravy Also make sure you have `preorder (Leaf n) = [n]` not `preorder  (Lead n) = n`.  Those `[ ]` are important.

Comment: preorder(Leaf n) = [n]
preorder(Node n treeL treeR) = [n] ++ preorder treeL ++ preorder treeR