# I want to make function maptree with standard ML

Tags: sml, smlnj

I want to make function maptree with standard ML.
If function f(x) = x + 1;
then

```
maptree(f, NODE(NODE(LEAF 1,LEAF 2),LEAF 3));
```

should make result

```
NODE(NODE(LEAF 2,LEAF 3),LEAF 4))
```

I write the code like below.

```
datatype 'a tree = LEAF of 'a | NODE of 'a tree * 'a tree;
fun f(x) = x + 1;
fun maptree(f, NODE(X, Y)) = NODE(maptree(f, X), maptree(f, Y))
| maptree(f, LEAF(X)) = LEAF(f X);
```

but when I execute this code like this

```
maptree(f, (NODE(NODE(LEAF 1,LEAF 2),LEAF 3)));
```

result is not I want to
(NODE(NODE(LEAF 2,LEAF 3),LEAF 4)))
but
NODE(NODE(LEAF #,LEAF #),LEAF 4)).
Why this happened(not a number but #)?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`#` is used by the REPL when the data structure it prints is deeper than a pre-set value. If you increase that value, you'll get the result you excepted. I assume you're using SML/NJ, which calls that setting `print.depth`:

```
sml -Cprint.depth=20
- maptree(f, (NODE(NODE(LEAF 1,LEAF 2),LEAF 3)));
val it = NODE (NODE (LEAF 2,LEAF 3),LEAF 4) : int tree
```

You can find more options like these by executing `sml -H`. Look them up under the "compiler print settings" section:

```
compiler print settings:
     print.depth                                          (max print depth)
     print.length                                        (max print length)
     print.string-depth                            (max string print depth)
     print.intinf-depth                        (max IntInf.int print depth)
     print.loop                                                (print loop)
     print.signatures                       (max signature expansion depth)
     print.opens                                             (print `open')
     print.linewidth                   (line-width hint for pretty printer)
```

Answer (score 0):

Some comments:

1. I would probably go with the definition

   ```
   datatype 'a tree = Leaf | Node of 'a tree * 'a * 'a tree
   ```

   so that trees with zero or two elements can also be expressed.
2. I would probably curry the tree map function

   ```
   fun treemap f Leaf = Leaf
     | treemap f (Node (l, x, r)) = Node (treemap f l, x, treemap f r)
   ```

   since you can then partially apply it, e.g. like:

   ```
   (* 'abstree t' returns t where all numbers are made positive *)
   val abstree = treemap Int.abs

   (* 'makeFullTree n' returns a full binary tree of size n *)
   fun makeFullTree 0 = Leaf
     | makeFullTree n =
       let val subtree = makeFullTree (n-1)
       in Node (subtree, n, subtree)
       end

   (* 'treetree t' makes an int tree into a tree of full trees! *)
   val treetree = treemap makeFullTree
   ```
3. You may at some point want to [fold a tree](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17683692/235908), too.